# Avoid "appinfo" page on Notification panel action

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I wrote a [long live service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29), so as per defined flow, it launches Notification Panel.
and launches notification panel without adding any **Intent**. Now if I perform click on panel action item, it launches the **"app info"** page.

[image]

Is there any way to avoid calling this **"App Info"** page.

If same perform from normal service instead of [permanent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)...then there's no issue, Panel action works as per defined behaviour.

Any idea/suggestion here?

Comment: Isn't the app info only shown if you long-press on the notification and then click on the text below the notificcation?

Comment: This is different—it's the `contentIntent` that the ActivityManager adds to your foreground service's `Notification` if it doesn't have one.

Comment: @Darwind if you don't add any pending intent action..then default it launch AppInfo page.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended; when starting a service in the foreground, your `Notification` is required to have a `contentIntent` that takes users somewhere helpful (i.e. somewhere that allows them to see what your service is doing and, if desired, stop it). If you attempt to `startForeground` without this intent, the Activity Manager will supply the one you're encountering—namely, taking the user to the Installed App Info page where they can stop the service.

Comment: Either don't make your service foreground, or specify a notification with a valid `contentIntent` when you `startForeground`.